# Panda dataframe lambda on data with Nan values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe with 2 numerical columns containing a few Nan values.

I calculate percentage diff between col1 and col2 with the following lambda:

```
df.apply(lambda row: round((row.iloc[0]-row.iloc[1])/row.iloc[0]*100), axis=1)
```

But rounding fails where the result is Nan. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Only apply the function to rows that don't contain missing values:

   `df.loc[df.notnull().all(axis=1), ].apply(lambda row: round((row.iloc[0]-row.iloc[1])/row.iloc[0]*100), axis=1)`

   (note that this particular implementation checks that *all* cls are nonmissing -- alter accordingly if there are additional cols in your df that you haven't told us about)
2. Check if either value is missing as part of the function:

   `df.apply(lambda row: round((row.iloc[0]-row.iloc[1])/row.iloc[0]*100) if row.iloc[0:2].notnull().all(), axis=1)`